# how to get the parameter value from the query string in codigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I am passing a id in a href tag. I want this id to be diplayed in the controller. can any one please help me out. I have seen the similar question in stack overflow and I have tried the all the  ways but none is working. can anyone help me out please.

Mycontroller

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Url extends CI_Controller
{

    public function menu1( $product_id;)
    {
        echo $product_id;
        // $data1 = $this->uri->segment(4);
        // $id['data'] =$data1;
        // $this->load->view('menu1',$id);
        //$this->input->get('id', TRUE);
    }
    public function menu2()
    {
        $this->load->view('menu2');
    }
    public function menu3()
    {
        $this->load->view('menu3');
    }
}

?>
```

View file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="">
            <?php $id=1;

            ?>

                 <li><a href='<?php echo base_url("Url/menu1?id=$id")?>' class="update">menu1</a></li>

                  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Url/menu2')?>" class="update">menu2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Url/menu3')?>" class="update">menu3</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

                                <div id="body" class="col-lg-12" >

                                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
      <script>
    $(function()

        {
            $('.update').click(function(event)
            {

            event.preventDefault();
            //$('.update').removeClass("active");
            //$(this).addClass("active");
            $('#body').load($(this).attr('href')); 
            });
        });

</script> 
</html>
```

menu1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $data; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to google your own question: https://www.google.pt/search?q=ajax%3A+how+to+get+the+parameter+value+from+the+query+string+in+codigniter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=LQx_WYPfM4TY8geM7bmABA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View:**

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Url/menu1?id=').$id?>" class="update">menu1</a></li>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function menu1()
{
    $data['product_id'] = $this->input->get('id');
    // echo $product_id;
    $this->load->view('menu1',$data);
}
```

In order to display the `product_id` in `menu1.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php echo $product_id; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i found the mistake actually i was doing like this $product_id = $this->input->get('$id');   but it should be  $product_id = $this->input->get('$id'); anyways thank you shihas

Comment: In the `$this->input->get('$id');` you don't want to use `$id` but just `id` is enough.